# How do I make a hamburger menu display on the right side?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu, jquery-animate

I have been working on making one of our sites mobile friendly and am running into trouble. I know that conventional practice is to put the hamburger on the left and make the content slide to the right but I would like to do the exact opposite and I hope that someone can help me. I have found a [great tutorial](http://www.ymc.ch/en/how-to-make-a-hamburger-a-menu-for-mobile-websites/) on how to create everything and have done that.

I have edited the JS file and css file but nothing is working.

This is what I changed in the JS file:

```
//set margin for the whole container with a jquery UI animation
    jQuery("#container").animate({ "marginRight": ["70%", 'easeOutExpo'] }, {
        duration: 700
    });

//set margin for the whole container back to original state with a jquery UI animation
    jQuery("#container").animate({ "marginRight": ["0", 'easeOutExpo'] }, {
        duration: 700,
```

In the css file, I simply changed any rule that was "right: 0;" to "left: 0;" and visa versa. I just don't know why its not sliding the content to the left. If I debug in firebug, the code appears to be working but nothing happens on the site. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you change "marginRight" to "margin-right" ?

Comment: no it's not about `margin-righ` or `marginRight`

Comment: Unfortunately without a jsFiddle or a link to the problem site we're shooting in the dark here @OMiD

Comment: yes @user2939047 could you please make a fiddle ?

Comment: I also wrote a guide for this in case it is helpful for you: http://blog.nightsprout.com/post/67400040170/hamburger-menus-and-how-to-make-them This is an example of how to write the hamburger menu from scratch. I believe it may serve you better in the end to be able to write one on your own, rather than rely on a copy/paste (in this instance). If you direct message me, I am happy to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it' difficult to understand without including the script, but i tried to figure it out, here are the changes you should modify.
Further more there are **no marginRight** at jQuery animate option.

change:

```
//set margin for the whole container with a jquery UI animation
jQuery("#container").animate({ "marginRight": ["70%", 'easeOutExpo'] }, {
  duration: 700
});
```

into:

```
jQuery("#container").animate({"marginLeft": ["-70%", 'easeOutExpo']}, {
  duration: 700
});
```

at the **CSS**:
seek for **`#hamburger`**
change **`float:left;`** into **`float:right;`**

seek for **nav** element
change **`left: 0px;`** into **`right:0px;`**

EDIT: change **`left: 0px;`** into **`right:-20px;`**
 [update working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp2Kz/2/)

the last seek for **`#contentLayer`**
 change **`right: 0;`** into **`left:0;`**

here is [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp2Kz/1/), enjoy the modification

Comment: Wow, that's great! I was just going to provide all of the code but I suppose I don't need to now. My apologies for not including more at first. Just figured a link to the tutorial and the lines I changed would be enough. The jQuery change doesn't make a bit of sense but if it works it works. It's just strange that I could watch the code change in firebug after I changed "marginLeft" to "marginRight", even though nothing was happening on the site.

Comment: an advice: for future question please submit complete code, live demo, and whats the problem persist after you die trying ;)